# Out of memory exception while retrieving large file using SOAP webservice

Tags: java, web-services, soap, mtom, datahandler

I'm struggling to read a large file transmitted through a SOAP based web service. The client code is failing with Out of memory exception. I'm using MTOM to send the binary data, hoping that would be able to take care of transmitting and reading large file. The file size in question is 750mb. I'm using apache cxf. Here's the web services endpoint implentation.

```
@MTOM
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.test.contentservice.service.IContentService")
@BindingType(value=javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP11HTTP_MTOM_BINDING)
public class ContentServiceImpl implements IContentService {

@Override
    public ContentResponse getFile(ContentRequest req) {
        ContentResponse res = new ContentResponse();
        try {
            File file = this.contentManager.getFile(req);
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
            DataHandler dataHandler = new DataHandler(source);
            res.setFileData(dataHandler);
            res.setFileName(file.getName());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Spring entry

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="contentService" implementor="#contentServiceImpl"
        address="/contentservice">
        <jaxws:dataBinding>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding">
                <property name="marshallerProperties">
                    <map>
                        <entry>
                            <key>
                                <value>jaxb.encoding</value>
                            </key>
                            <value>UTF-8</value>
                        </entry>
                    </map>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </jaxws:dataBinding>
        <jaxws:properties>
            <entry key="mtom-enabled" value="true" />
        </jaxws:properties>
    </jaxws:endpoint>
```

As you can notice, "mtom-enabled" is turned on.

The client code is generated using cxf wsdl2java tool. Here's a sample client code

```
ContentResponse res =  new ContentResponse();
        try{
            res = getRegisterPort().getFile(req);
            DataHandler dataHandler = res.getFileData();
            if(dataHandler!=null){
                    final InputStream in = dataHandler.getInputStream(); 
                    byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
            }
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Error in invoking getContent service",ex);
        }
```

Here's the response object

```
@XmlAccessorType( XmlAccessType.FIELD )
public class ContentResponse extends ContentServiceResponseBase {

    private String content;
    private String source;
    private String fileName;
    @XmlMimeType("application/octet-stream")
    private DataHandler fileData;
// Getter / Setter ...
}
```

I'm setting the mtom at the client code level as well

`final BindingProvider bpAdmin = (BindingProvider) port;
        bpAdmin.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, curlUrl);
        SOAPBinding binding = (SOAPBinding)bpAdmin.getBinding();
        binding.setMTOMEnabled(true);`

jvm entry is as follows :

```
java -Xms64m -Xmx6144m
```

And the exception :

`Exception in thread "taskExecutor-12" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
       at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2882)
       at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:100)
       at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:515)
       at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:189)
       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.handleCharacters(StAXStreamConnector.java:312)
       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:176)
       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:349)
       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.BridgeImpl.unmarshal(BridgeImpl.java:109)
       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.api.Bridge.unmarshal(Bridge.java:222)
       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.ResponseBuilder$DocLit.readResponse(ResponseBuilder.java:514)
       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:110)
       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
       at $Proxy33.getFile(Unknown Source)`

Not sure what I'm missing here, any pointer will be highly appreciated.

- Thanks

Comment: are you sure the JVM options are picked up by JVM?

Comment: @Funtik .. "ps -ef" shows the right jvm parameters

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE

Could you try a [StreamingDataHandler](https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/jax-ws-20-fcs/arch/com/sun/xml/ws/developer/StreamingDataHandler.html) in this case when sending the data, with a call to [readOnce](https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/jax-ws-20-fcs/arch/com/sun/xml/ws/developer/StreamingDataHandler.html#readOnce%28%29) on the server?

Reference that you can adapt, just for the streaming handler part:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13734/mtom.htm

---

Is the issue occurring in *IOUtils.toByteArray*?

If not try to narrow down the operation where the exception is thrown and update your question.

Comment: Its not even reaching if(dataHandler!=null){
                    final InputStream in = dataHandler.getInputStream(); 
                    byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(in); The out of memory exception is happening at DataHandler dataHandler = res.getFileData();

Comment: I'm using apache cxf.My understanding is CXF just supports streaming directly without requiring a special StreamingDataHandler. StreamingDataHandler is applicable to JAX-WS.